# Using functions in data.table on = .( ) argument when joining

Tags: r, data.table

I thought `data.table` would accept arguments with functions in `on=.()` argument because `by=.()` accepts functions, but it seems it does not.

Here's what I was trying to do.

```
# DT1 has "date" column and DT2 has "datadate", "month" column 
DT1[DT2, on = .( year(date) = year(datadate))]

# or

DT1[DT2, on = .( year(date) <= year(datadate), month(date) = month)]
```

Is there a succinct way to implement above on the fly?

Comment: It is matching on the column names.  So you may not need to create a column first

Comment: Please provide a reproducible example along with expected output. Read about [how to give a reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269).

Comment: It is a pending feature request in data.table github repository

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example that does a join based on "year" extracted from two differently named date columns with `year()` and calculated in the j-index of two `data.table`s

IMO this is not as pretty as your #1 there that doesn't work, but maybe it gets you closer to what you wanted.

```r
library(data.table)

DT1 <- data.table(date = strftime(c("2020-01-01","2019-01-02"), "%Y-%m-%d"), x = c(1,2))
DT2 <- data.table(datadate = strftime(c("2020-01-01","2019-01-02","2020-02-03","2019-03-04"), "%Y-%m-%d"), y = 3:6)

DT1[,year := year(date)][DT2[, year := year(datadate)], on = list(year = year)]
#>          date x year   datadate y
#> 1: 2020-01-01 1 2020 2020-01-01 3
#> 2: 2019-01-02 2 2019 2019-01-02 4
#> 3: 2020-01-01 1 2020 2020-02-03 5
#> 4: 2019-01-02 2 2019 2019-03-04 6
```

<sup>Created on 2020-12-06 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>